# How to create and populate pandas row based on other dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I've created `df2` and `df3` from the original `df` based on certain conditions.
Now, I want to map it back to `df` by creating a new row `Subtype` and label the row value as `Table2` if the column name matches `df2`, whereas it would be `Table3` if it matches the column name of `df3`.

`df`

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 |
| Second | 1 | 5 | 9 | 13 | 17 | 21 | 25 |
| Third | 2 | 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 | 22 | 26 |
| Fourth | 3 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 19 | 23 | 27 |
| Fifth | 1 | 2 | 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

`df2`

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0 | 4 | 8 |
| Second | 1 | 5 | 9 |
| Third | 2 | 6 | 10 |
| Fourth | 3 | 7 | 11 |
| Fifth | 1 | 2 | 3 |

`df3`

|  | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 12 | 16 | 20 |
| Second | 13 | 17 | 21 |
| Third | 14 | 18 | 22 |
| Fourth | 15 | 19 | 23 |

Expected output:

`df`

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 24 |
| Second | 1 | 5 | 9 | 13 | 17 | 21 | 25 |
| Third | 2 | 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 | 22 | 26 |
| Fourth | 3 | 7 | 11 | 15 | 19 | 23 | 27 |
| Fifth | 1 | 2 | 3 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Subtype | Table2 | Table2 | Table2 | Table3 | Table3 | Table3 | Table3 |

Comment: In row 4 of df - the title is first - but in df2 and df3 row 4 is second - what governs the movement from first to second?

Comment: oops, `df` is the expected output. The original dataframe is exactly like the `df` minus the last row.

Comment: I've amended my question

Comment: There is no name for the first column, I am guessing you missed it? or is it unnamed?

Comment: @no_hex `First`, `Second`, `Third` etc are the indices. `A`, `B`, `C` etc are the column names. The first column name is `A`.

Comment: @melolilili The first column name is Unnamed, as you have 7 column names for 8 columns in total in `df1`

Comment: column `G` is NOT in `df3`, why it should be marked as `Table3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
d2 = {col: "Table2" for col in df2.columns}
d3 = {col: "Table3" for col in df3.columns}
​
df.loc["Subtype"] = list(df.columns.map({**d2, **d3}))
```

Output :

```
print(df)
              A       B       C       D       E       F     G
First         0       4       8    12.0    16.0    20.0  24.0
Second        1       5       9    13.0    17.0    21.0  25.0
Third         2       6      10    14.0    18.0    22.0  26.0
Fourth        3       7      11    15.0    19.0    23.0  27.0
Fifth         1       2       3     NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN
Subtype  Table2  Table2  Table2  Table3  Table3  Table3   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this maybe it can help you.

```
# Create a new row for Subtype
subtype = []
for column in df.columns:
    if column in df2.columns:
        subtype.append('Table2')
    elif column in df3.columns:
        subtype.append('Table3')
df.loc['Subtype'] = subtype
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `df2` and `df3` may theoretically have different number of columns. Hence, df*3 is not ideal. The rows may also be mixed up

Comment: Alright let me change it to general

Answer (score 0):

```py
subtype = ['Table2' if col_name in df2.columns else 'Table3' for col_name in df1.columns[1:]]

df1.set_index(df1.columns[0], inplace=True)

subtype_row = pd.DataFrame([subtype], index=["Subtype"], columns=df1.columns)

df1 = pd.concat([df1, subtype_row])
```

The changes are in the following order:

1. Creating a list of `Table2` or `Table3` accordingly, starting from `df1.columns[1:]` skipping the first unnamed column.
2. Setting the first column to be the index of the rows, as we don't want to see numbered rows.
3. Creating a new dataframe out of the list we built before (step 1)
4. concatenating the two dataframes

---

Output:

```
              A       B       C       D       E       F       G
First         0       4       8    12.0    16.0    20.0    24.0
Second        1       5       9    13.0    17.0    21.0    25.0
Third         2       6      10    14.0    18.0    22.0    26.0
Fourth        3       7      11    15.0    19.0    23.0    27.0
Fifth         1       2       3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Subtype  Table2  Table2  Table2  Table3  Table3  Table3  Table3
```